# Why can I not split a .ape file?

Tags: audio, conversion, flac

I would like to split a `.ape` album into individual tracks in `.flac` format using a `.cue` sheet. For this I followed a [tutorial](http://en.linuxreviews.org/HOWTO_splitt_lossless_audio_files_%28ape,_flac,_wv,_wav%29_using_.cue_files) I found. In short I pass this command to the terminal:

```
cuebreakpoints example.cue | shnsplit -o flac example.ape
```

But I get the following error back:

```
shnsplit: warning: failed to read data from input file using format: [ape]
shnsplit:          + you may not have permission to read file: [example.ape]
shnsplit:          + arguments may be incorrect for decoder: [mac]
shnsplit:          + verify that the decoder is installed and in your PATH
shnsplit:          + this file may be unsupported, truncated or corrupt
shnsplit: error: cannot continue due to error(s) shown above
```

Unfortunately I don't know how to overcome this issue. One thing I think can be discarded is the file being corrupt since I had the same error with another `.ape` and I have followed this procedure with origin `.flac` files with no problem.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/251362/split-monkeyaudio-ape-cue-log-of-whole-audio-cd-into-mp3-of-individual Reproduced on Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 17):

**`shntool` on Ubuntu 14.04**

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:flacon
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y flacon
shntool split -f *.cue -o flac -t '%n - %p - %t' *.ape
```

`flacon` is a GUI for `shntool`, but it comes with all the codecs it needs...

In particular, the `flacon` [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~flacon/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) furnishes the `mac` package (Monkey's Audio Console), on which `flacon` depends, which has the `mac` CLI tool, which seems to be the main missing ingredient.

Comment: Works well under Linux Mint 17.2, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From the error message it looks like you don't have [Monkey's Audio Codec](http://www.monkeysaudio.com/index.html) installed. It is not mentioned as a dependency in the HOWTO you refer to but for decoding `.ape` that is necessary.

You can download the source from the link at the bottom of the [Developers TAB](http://www.monkeysaudio.com/developers.html)